# How to call method of controller in .module file with dependency injection

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I have class named Book.

```
class Popups
{
  private $entityQuery;
  private $entityTypeManager;

  public function __construct(QueryFactory $entityQuery, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this->entityQuery = $entityQuery;
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }



public function read($cid)
  {
    $nodes = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'book', 'cid' => $cid ]);

    return $nodes;
  }

}
```

Now I have books.module file where I need to call read method;
how to call that method

```
$book = new Book();  // what param should i pass here
$book->read($cid)
```

Comment: Why not add the class to mymodule.services.yml and inject the core services there?

Comment: That won’t work because the constructor is expecting arguments. Register this class as a service, and call it with \Drupal::service() instead.

Comment: @4k4 there are some database related queries written in read function with searvices and in .module file I only need to call that read method.

Comment: I don't understand why database queries would be a reason not to use a service.

Answer (score 7):

Add the class to *mymodule.services.yml* and inject the core services there:

*mymodule.services.yml*

```
services:
  mymodule.book:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Book
    arguments: ['@entity.query', '@entity_type.manager']
```

Then use the service in procedural code:

```
\Drupal::service('mymodule.book')->read($cid)
```

Comment: I don't wish to in this way my question was how to call controller function in module

Comment: At the moment the function is not a controller. However, if you want to add a controller method to the class, you can do this in a service as well, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes. Which is IMHO a better way for dependency injection anyway, and you can use the service resources in multiple places, without the need to create multiple instances.

Comment: `I don't wish to in this way` this is how its done, you don't `new Class()` anything in procedural - this will resolve dependencies and take care of instantiation for you.

Comment: You may not want to do it this way, but you've come on a Drupal QA site and asked a Drupal question, to which you've been given a Drupal answer. If you want a non-Drupal way, you're likely on your own to find a solution.